# Passing compile time string to a class

Tags: c#, generics, constants, compile-time

I need to pass const string to a class at compile time. I have a MigrationHistoryRepository class. And I need to have a different schema name for each DbContext that uses it. I was hoping something like this generic aprroach would work but it does not. Is there a way to do this?

```
public abstract class TextDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConnectionString))
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
            options.ReplaceService<IHistoryRepository, MigrationHistoryRepository<"MyTestSchema">>(); // Chaning EF history naming convention
        }
    }
}

public class MigrationHistoryRepository<T> : SqlServerHistoryRepository where T : string
{
    public MigrationHistoryRepository(HistoryRepositoryDependencies dependencies)
        : base(dependencies)
    {
    }

    protected override string TableName { get { return "migration_history"; } }

    protected override string TableSchema => T;

    protected override void ConfigureTable(EntityTypeBuilder<HistoryRow> history)
    {
        base.ConfigureTable(history);

        history.HasKey(h => h.MigrationId).HasName($"{TableName}_pkey");
        history.Property(h => h.MigrationId).HasColumnName("id");
        history.Property(h => h.ProductVersion).HasColumnName("product_version");
    }
}
```

!!!!!! EDIT !!!!!!

Edit was moved to a separate question

[DependencyInjection cannot find the assebly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66891646/dependencyinjection-cannot-find-the-assebly)

Comment: C# generics are not C++ templates, and you can't treat them as such

Comment: Ok and is there any way arround that?

Comment: What about `MigrationHistoryRepository<MyTestSchema>`? Did I miss anything here?

Comment: It's a simple assembly loading failure. "System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'TestUtilsEntityFramework, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: This assembly is in the same directory as WebApp. Everything else I use in this assembly works. So what do I do to fix this please? By the way I get same error even when I use PublishSingleFile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass strings to generics, only types.  But here you have a type to pass.

```
public class MigrationHistoryRepository<T> : SqlServerHistoryRepository where T : DbContext
```

and

```
options.ReplaceService<IHistoryRepository, MigrationHistoryRepository<TextDbContext>>();
```

And then derive the schema name from data availabable from `typeof(T)`, like its name, or a custom attribute you put on it, or a static property or method invoked through reflection.